# Making an object become an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to make a JavaScript object become an array? That is, while keeping its existing attributes, start behaving like an array with regard to `length`, `push`, `forEach` etc? I had the vague idea that this might be possible by reassigning the prototype but some attempts to do this by trial and error haven't yielded any results.

Comment: A two-dimensional array?

Comment: JQuery shows you how [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Comment: That seems like a rather weird thing to do. What do you want it for? You can build an array out of an array-like object pretty simply, but transmuting a non-array-like object into an array?

Comment: Googling "javascript convert object to array" beings up loads of results, the top ones from SO.

Comment: yeah, i think the best bet will be to run the object through jquery's `map` or something, pushing each value into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. While you could theoretically (through [non-standard ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)) reassign the prototype, it will not change its internal `[[Class]]` and get a magic `.length` property.

Instead, try to copy all the properties of the object onto a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, other than for access to `.length`, `.push()`, and  `forEach`, as you mentioned. As far as I know, you cannot force these properties/functions to work on an object, but you can certainly get around them:

`.length` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700/3366929)):

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// Get the size of an object
var size = Object.size(myObj);
```

`.push()`:

```
obj.key = value; //there isn't a much shorter way to add something to an object since you have to specify a key and a value
```

`forEach`:

```
for(key in obj){
  var value;
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     value = obj[key]; //you now have access to the key and the value in each iteration of obj
  }
}
```